# display full form field error message below field - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This seems like it should be both simple and common, but I've been trying to display the full message version of the field errors below each field.

I've done many searches, some reference error_messages_for but it's deprecated. What I've got shows the errors, but not the full message form...

Can anyone help me understand how to show the error messages next to the form field?

```
<%= form_for @postcode, :url => search_store_locations_path, :html => {:class => "form span16"} do |f| %>
          <div class="control-group <%= "error" if @postcode.errors[:search_token].size > 0 %>">
              <%= f.label :search_token, "Suburb or Postcode", :class => "control-label" %>
              <div class="controls">
                <%= f.text_field :search_token%>
                ***<%= raw("<span class='help-inline'>") + @postcode.errors[:search_token].join(", ") + raw("</span>") if @postcode.errors[:search_token].size > 0 %>***
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <%= button_tag "Search stores", :class => "btn btn-success" %>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```